# How can I add a git ignored file like .env.prod to GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

I cannot commit this file for security reasons but I need to get this .env.prod file on the server somehow.

Is there a way to specify a secret file to push to the server from GitHub actions?

I only see a way to set environment variables for the action not the server

Ssh and rsync using a GitHub actikn

Comment: Did you try setting the contents of this file as a secret?

Comment: Yes, figure out I have to do it that way and write it out.

Comment: Why do you need to do that at all? The point of `.env` files is for development, to simulate what you have in production, which is _actual environment variables_.

Answer (score 0):

I have both prod and dev on same server. Prod is released from `release` branch and all other branches are considered dev environment.

Any json has to be base64 encoded in the secret...the issue is this may be echo'd out in logs so its not 100% safe.

```
      - name: Set env file and jwk.json for release
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }}
        run: |
          echo "${{secrets.PRODUCTION_ENV }}" > .env.prod
          ln -sf .env.prod .env
          echo "${{secrets.PRODUCTION_JWK}}" | base64 --decode > jwk.json

      - name: Set env file and jwk.json for development
        if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
        run: |
          echo "${{secrets.DEVELOPMENT_ENV }}" > .env.dev
          ln -sf .env.dev .env
          echo "${{secrets.DEVELOPMENT_JWK}}" | base64 --decode > jwk.json
```